# concat n rows together in a select that contains n rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have a table that contains two columns id_readings (Auto_Inc) and name like so

| id_readings | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | jim |
| 2 | jon |
| 3 | jun |
| 4 | esd |
| 5 | job |
| 6 | jif |
| 9 | jef |
| 11 | pol |
| 12 | pil |
| 16 | jml |
| 19 | cid |

So if i want to concat every 3 rows together, regardless of the value id_readings or name, it should look like this

| concat |
| --- |
| jim,jon,jun |
| esd,job,jif |
| jef,pol,pil |
| jml,cid |

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: `string_agg(name, ',')` with `GROUP BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_readings) / 3` should do it

Comment: @Bergi, window functions (such as `ROW_NUMBER`) are not allowed in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Bergi, also, even if using `ROW_NUMBER` in `GROUP BY` was allowed, the row number would need to be adjusted by the divisor - 1 or its equivalent in modular arithmetic; e.g., `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) + 2) / 3`. Without this adjustment, the first group would have at most two names.

Comment: @JonH i was thinking the same thing in the beginning, but i think this is just a hint not the way you should write it.

I'll post the way i solved my issue with his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for those want to know here's how i solved it, with the help of @Bergi answer :

```
SELECT string_agg(name, ',')
FROM (
   SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY id_readings) / 3 AS group_id
   FROM data
) AS test
GROUP BY group_id
```

Thanks again to him

Answer (score 2):

The following query will produce the requested results:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) - 1) / 3 AS group_id, name
             FROM some_table)
SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ', ')
  FROM t
 GROUP BY group_id;
```

The ordering of the names is not specified. All but at most one group will have three names.